# Disabling allowance for Coins and NFTs?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, security, allowance, phishing

[Allowance phishing attacks](https://twitter.com/metamasksupport/status/1425762013075103745?lang=en) are on the rise, and the number of use cases for allowance for erc20 and NFTs seems to be limited.  Is there any problem with disabling allowance, perhaps with a new standard? Would this cause many problems in the Ethereum ecosystem?

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that allowance will be disabled for ERC20 tokens. It is heavily used by on-chain markets like uniswap.

There are newer standards, like [EIP-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155), that improve with `interface ERC1155TokenReceiver`. The problem is that it isn't backward compatible so it requires to deploy new contract versions. Recently, new tokens started to use EIP-1155.

Comment: If I am not mistaken Uniswap V3 requires a deposit and no longer uses an allowance.  Selling your NFT on OpenSea uses an Allow grant.  I am aware of the 1155 receiver, I don't think this was intended to prevent metamask phishing for allowance.